# How can this be done in O(nlogn) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I had a question on my exams for which I had to come up with an efficient algorithm. The problem was like this:

We have some objects which have two properties:

```
H = <1,1000000> 
R = <1,1000000>
```

we can insert one object into another if `H1>H2` and `R1>R2`. The input contains pairs of `H` and `R`, one pair per line. if the current object can be inserted in any previous objects, we choose such with the least `H` and then we destroy both of them. print the number of left objects in the output.

I wonder how can this problem be solved in `O(n.log(n))` time complexity using binary search trees or segment tree, or with fenwick tree.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should add an example input and output  so the problem is really clear.  If I got it right (which I am not 100% sure from the text of yours) I would first sort the items by `H,R` which is `O(n.log(n))` and then just scan  the list of objects in `~O(n)` scan (marking deleted objects instead of deleting them) printing only left items

Comment: @Spektre, your scan would be `O(n**2)` if the number of deleted objects approaches `n`.

Comment: @SergeRogatch no as I wrote no actual delete will be done just mark item as deleted instead ... as this is just sequential scan (similar to merging 2 sorted list) it should be still around `~O(n)` Yu always continue fom last used index not from start in each iteration

Comment: This can be done using balanced binary search tree, where searching, deleting takes O(logn), therefore the total complexity will be O(nlogn)

Comment: @RickSanchez: but how?

Comment: @Spektre , last used index may be worse in terms of `R` if you sort by `H`.

Comment: Could you explain a solution using binary search tree?

Comment: Will `O(n * log(n) * log(n))` do? @shotakobaxidze

Comment: no, i need O(n*logn)

Comment: is there any way to solve this with interval trees or balanced binary tree? if yes, please explain the whole solution

Answer (score 1):

A solution with fenwick tree, as follows;

- Let's sort the whole array by `R` at first (right now, we are not caring about `H`), and assign each item a token (which is equal to it's position in the sorted array).
- Let's get back to our original array. We are going to run a sweep on the given array. Say, we have a fenwick tree, which will, instead of cumulative sum, store maximum (from beginning to that position) only for `H`.
- For an item, say, we couldn't fit it into another item. Then we'll insert it into the tree. We'll insert in such position that is equal to it's token.
- So, right now, we've a fenwick tree, which contains only the items we've dealt with till now. Other values are 0. The items in the tree are positioned in `R` sorted order.
- Now, how to find out if we can fit current item to another object? We can actually run a binary search (upper bound) on fenwick tree for current item's `H`. And, as the items are already sorted in `R` order, instead of whole tree, we need to search in the effective range.
- Binary search in fenwick tree can be done in `O(log(n))`. Check out the **Find index with given cumulative frequency** part of [this](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/) article.